# How to do a TIMESTAMP comparison in mongo DB?

Tags: mongodb

I have the following field in all my documents. And the Timestamp below will always be in string and I have no control to change it into any other type.

```
{ "TIMESTAMP": "2017-09-07T16:43:08.707-04:00" }
```

Since it is `-04:00` the timestamp is in EST. but it can be in any timezone like -05:00 or -6:00 or whatever

The goal is to get all the documents that match the following criteria

```
currentTime > TIMSETAMP + 4 hours
```

where currentTime is in UTC and it is something I generate when I query.

I tried something like the following and I am not sure if there is anything wrong with this approach.

`(new Date()- ISODate("2017-09-07T16:43:08.707-04:00"))/(60*60*1000) > 4`

Comment: What about when day light savings(-05:00) is in effect ? You should save the documents as with TIMESTAMP as  datetime type instead of string , which is by default UTC timezone and you can compare them directly using $gte operator.

Comment: @Veeram Yes it can be -05:00 or -06:00 or -07:00 or something else. This is why I just want to convert into UTC first and then add 4 hours and then I generate my currentTime  in UTC for comparison. The "TIMESTAMP" will be in string and I have no control to change it.

Comment: @Veeram I edited my question with what I tried and I am not sure if there is anything wrong with that?